# join multiple relation tables

Tags: php, mysql, join, left-join

i have a table food

```
food_id     food_name  

  1           chappathi
```

and another table category

```
category_id    category_name

  1              non-veg
  2              nutrition
```

and a relation table food_category

```
food_id    category_id

  1          1
  1          2
```

where the food_id is the foriegn key of food_id in food table, category_id is the foriegn_key of category_id in the category table, **there will be case no categories for a food**
i have tried

```
 $sql=      "SELECT * FROM food f
            LEFT JOIN food_category fc
            ON f.food_id=fc.food_id
            LEFT JOIN category c
            ON fc.category_id=c.category_id"
```

it gives me more than one food items, what i want is

```
item name: chappathi
categories: non-veg, nutrition
------------------------------
second row of result set if there is any
```

Comment: What is your result expected to be ?

Comment: As I can see that your query is correct and it will give you more than one record. As it has two categories associated at food_category table.

Comment: I want only the food item with id 1 if there is any categories in the result table i want to fetch it to the food item 1 as an array or something else, so i can display it as chappathi with nutriention and non-veg category @SIDU

Comment: Your question is very clear and good formatted. It's easier if you add the expected result to your quesiton.

Comment: i have added @SIDU

Comment: You can take a look at GROUP_CONCAT, but I think it's better to handle display issues such as this in application code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT f.food_name AS item_name,  GROUP_CONCAT(c.category_name SEPARATOR ', ') AS categories
FROM food f
LEFT JOIN food_category fc ON f.food_id=fc.food_id
LEFT JOIN category c ON fc.category_id=c.category_id
GROUP BY f.id
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Thank you all for answering @all

Answer (score 0):

What you need is group_concat:

```
SELECT f.food_name, group_concat(c.category_name) AS Cat
FROM food AS f
LEFT JOIN food_category AS fc ON f.food_id = fc.food_id
LEFT JOIN category AS c ON c.category_id = fc.category_id
GROUP BY f.food_id
```

Comment: `GROUP BY 1,2` is very specific to the current content of the table. You should always group by a column name.

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'group_concat(c.category_name) AS Cat FROM food AS f LEFT JOIN food_categ' at line 1 @SIDU

Comment: @Ranjith I tested with mine, no error, any column names typo with your real situation?

Answer (score 0):

Agreed with @strawberry. Look at group_concat.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Answer (score 0):

The query should be written as below to fetch the food name and its categories list.

```
 SELECT f.food_name as ItemName,  
STUFF(
         (SELECT DISTINCT ',' + c.category_name
          FROM  food 
          LEFT JOIN food_category fc on fc.food_id= food.food_id
          LEFT JOIN category c ON fc.category_id =c.category_id                        
          FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')  AS Categories
FROM food f                    
 group by f.food_id, f.food_name
```

Please check it out.